# Why do I get AttributeError: 'BoardWriteForm' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: attributeerror

[image][image]

I keep getting AttributeError even though I check my codes again. I think there's nothing wrong but why this keeps happening? I checked the whole code that has'title' in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an `AttributeError`, it means in your case that the line with `self.title = ...` has not been executed before a reading call to the `title` attribute has been made.

To solve this, you could e.g. append

```
self.title = ""
```

to the `__init__()` method of your form. This would guarantee that a value would exist.

To further debug this, we would need to see all calls to the `title` attribute and the exact line where the error occurs.